# DELETE FROM tab WHERE name IN ( name1 , name2 ) :fails / ok: DELETE FROM tab WHERE id IN ( 1 , 2 )

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row, where-in

Error deleting record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right ** syntax to use near ' name2' at line 1 **

```
  tab:
  __________
  id , name
  __________
   1 , name1
   2 , name2
   3 , name3



  DELETE FROM  tab  WHERE  id   IN ( 1 , 2 )
Record deleted successfully!
```

but ERROR :

```
  DELETE FROM  tab  WHERE  name   IN ( name1 , name2 )
Error deleting record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' name2' at line 1
```

I like to delete the data with  name1 and name2 , I do not know the id

Please help , thank you

Comment: Recommend: SQL tutorial and a ‘workbench’ to rapidly play with SQL to identify and fix syntax errors. There are also “SQL fiddle” sites online so syntax can be tested easily in many cases.

Comment: "name1" , 'name2'    Record deleted successfully  thank you - I was tyred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are string values, you need single quotes:

```
DELETE FROM  tab 
    WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2')
```